# Tab item images are not displaying perfectly in custom tab bar

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

[image]

Here is my code to set images

```
[tabItem0 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home_selected.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home_selected.png"]];    
[tabItem1 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"info.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"info.png"]];     
[tabItem2 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"like.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"like.png"]];        
[tabItem3 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"twitter.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"twitter.png"]];
```

I am taking height of every image same as of tab bar height but it is looking like this and a black border at the bottom also which covers some part of images please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: What about the size of images???

Comment: you taking height of every image means?

Answer (score 0):

Generally I assign images to tab bar items like this

```
viewController.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Twiiter" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Home_Tab.png"] tag:0];
```

You can try this right and also check for tab bar image size i guess it is around 30x30.